# Workaround for Gazebo 2.2.6 not saving changes in obstacles into world file

Tags: gazebo-2.2, ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I wonder if there is a workaround to save changes in obstacles into world file in Gazebo 2.2.6. I know it is a bug for this version of gazebo:

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7452/save-as-feature-not-saving-light-info-into-world-file/

and I don't want to upgrade Gazebo to version 4.0 because I'm using ROS Indigo and the recommended version for that version of ROS is Gazebo 2.x:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14907/workaround-for-gazebo-2.2.6-not-saving-changes-in-obstacles-into-world-file/) by [andrestoga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2914/andrestoga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You should (and can) use gazebo7 with ROS indigo. Gazebo2 is deprecated, and I highly recommend upgrading.

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1